# How do i pass values into a function?

Tags: processing

In python, I can make a function that requires data to be passed in. For example, I can make a function like:

```
def functionName(x)
```

and can then use x within the function. When I try this in processing like:

```
void functionName(x)
```

it gives me the error message Error on "... VariableDeclaratorId".

Is there a way to pass in data in processing or java like in python?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-functions) is a tutorial on creating functions in Processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the type of the parameter. For example, if the value you want to be passed in is a float, you would define your function as:

```
void funtionName(float x)
```